# Why isn't my data pasting correctly when I copy and paste it within a For loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to another using VBA For loop. For some reason when I execute the below code the data is not being copied in one column under each other but in a strange format as shown below.

```
Sub Macro2()

For i = 110 To 116
For j = 1 To 1


Worksheets("overview of contracts").Activate
Range("A" & i).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("C" & j).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Worksheets("overview of contracts").Activate
'Range("B" & i).Select
'Selection.Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("D" & j).Select
'ActiveSheet.Paste

'Range("C" & i).Select
'Selection.Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("E" & j).Select
'ActiveSheet.Paste

 Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

This is the original data, what I am trying to achieve is copy that data to another sheet using a loop exactly in that format and sequence. 
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkcXU.png)

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba and all your problems will be over. Well not all of them, but this one at least.

Comment: What is the point of the loop with ```j```?

Comment: @Warcupine I know its stupid but I am very green with macros mate, would appreciate any help

Comment: What does your original data look like?

Comment: just simple data numbers and letters

Comment: @KylieJames can you post a screen from your original sample and the desired output? Would help a lot.

Comment: @Damian updated question

Comment: Another question, why are you looping through A110 to A116? you are not evaluating anything, why not just copying  `Range("A110:A116")` and paste it to the other sheet, @KylieJames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. It takes values in `sheet("overview of contacts")`, and copies their values to `sheet("Sheet1")` in column C, descending rows.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = 2
    For i = 110 To 116
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Overview of Contracts").Cells(i, 1).Value
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```